# Проблема @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object с в React

Tags: reactjs

Почему при каждом запуске сервера или билде React-приложения возникает это предупреждение?

"One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away."

Пакет установлен в node_modules/@babel, я также добавил его в devDependencies в package.json (с версией 1.0.0), но предупреждение остаётся. Как можно исправить ошибку?